# Maximum likelihood in linear regression

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

My understanding is that when we do maximum likelihood we want to choose parameters $\theta$ such that the probability of observing the actual, fixed data is maximized. That's how I understood it through a coin toss example.

So when we do linear regression we want to maximize the probability that we observe the actual values of the response $y_i$ dependent on every $x_i$ assuming that irreducible error $\epsilon ~ \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ .

Assuming I have all that right then **why do we have a distribution for each observation $y_i$**? Is this not fixed data that we are trying to best fit?

Very confused

Comment: Why do you have a distribution for flips if a coin? After all, those are fixed data, too.

Comment: So I'll put it as best as I can, when we have coin tosses and say 1 heads and 2 tails in observed data then yeah I can visualize that distribution pretty easily with a barplot or something. What's confusing with maximum likelihood is we seem to assume every $y_i$ has a normal distribution. How can that be when it's a single point whose value we have already observed?

Comment: The coin flips are also values we have already observed, aren’t they?

Comment: Yes and we want to find some parameter $\theta$ that has the highest probability to generate them

Comment: Can you apply that same logic to the linear regression?

Comment: Sure that's what I'm trying to do. We have some scatterplot of data and we know there's a line that provides a 'best fit' to that data with true unknown parameters $\theta = \beta_0, \beta_1$ (simplest case) such that $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 + \epsilon$. I just don't quite see why we'd have $y_i$ as normally distributed though

Comment: Hi AdmitalMunson: $y_{i}$ happens to be normally distributed because of $\epsilon$. but it didn't have to be. $\epsilon$ could have had some other distribution and then $y$ would have had that distribution but the concept of MLE would still apply. There's no special connection between ML and normality.  It sounds to me like you're quite close to understanding things.

Comment: Note that I should have mentioned that $\epsilon$ is assumed to be normally distributed ( usually in OLS ) but my point was that  that assumption can be relaxed and you could still calculate an MLE.